# EM radiation from processes without photon emission

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Would it be possible to create EM radiation, starting this process without photon emission from subatomic particles?

Comment: How could anything to do with light propagation be explained without photons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classical electromagnetic waves and quantum field theoretical photons describe the *same phenomena*—indeed, photons are modes of the field.

There is no distinction between "EM radiation" and "photon emission" except for how you frame the description.

So the answer is **"No."**

Comment: There's no way to generate photons by simply accelerating charges? I guess the point is that to accelerate a charge you have to create a potential that the particle is pushed by, and then photon radiation is due to the atom decreasing its now-increased energy.

Comment: @StevenSagona it still involves a photon.

Comment: Photons are *excitations* of the corresponding modes, but yes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty A photon, as in a localized quantum of energy and separate from other photons. What are corresponding modes and what about them gets excited? How do you know they’re excited?